# Can't open RStudio 1.1.423 after upgrade to Anaconda Navigator 1.8.7/Python 3.6 (Windows 10)

Tags: python, r, anaconda, rstudio

After upgrading Anaconda I am no longer able to run RStudio. When I launch it, the window opens for several seconds, then closes and is replaced with a "File Save" dialog box. The log file contains a "file not found" message, but there is no indication of the file name or location.

I have removed and re-installed, installed for all users and only me, tried different R engines, installed on two separate systems (one with no previous installs). I do not know what else to try. Any help would be appreciated!